# A weird deleted Puzzling.SE question

Tags: cipher, visual, mechanical-puzzles

So I was just browsing Puzzling as usual, when I stumbled upon a... to put it mildly, "strange" question:

[image: GIF]

The question seems to be permanently deleted now...

For those who disabled GIFs in their browser, here are pictures that together form the whole webpage of the question: [One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JlpP.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucEVN.png), [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4UDf.png). The question score constantly gets lower and when you hover over the word *"clouds"* (sorry for forgetting doing that in the GIF) a tooltip appears which says:

> to which I always returned to for orientation and only changed the height when I had to

**Edit:** Thanks to [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar) for [stitching all three parts together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuwBn.png). The missing parts between part 2 and 3 do not contain anything important.

---

Since the colored ciphertexts are hard to read:
**Orange**: `HUSOQTLNBSSALRDIDPNOKHFTHEXJVMDDJCCNCMMOTRTFRETJTXZGSBUPWRNOLZYVIRSHDEQKDRXVTQGRNMOSXDFNWEAINGWSQBBQYXFTWFHECINGVSO`
**Yellow**: `NJVZVOGYEVSGOGSJRKBASPBFOQMFHFJKUFEG`
**White**: `ITLAFSGWHOBTCHIEUOHETLHDVENSLESECDOAI`
**Blue**: `MGQPHPGRNKEAWQYG` <sub>**Edit:** Another mistake on my part, the intended ciphertext is `MGQPHPGRNKEAVPXF`. But as you can see only the last few letters were wrong, so it's not a major mistake and you would've still gotten part of the plaintext with the intended method before.</sub>
**Green**: `UDWTTERUDCTONOHGON`
**Red**: `ESTXHMWETZOYRIJOM`
**Gray** at the bottom of the page:

> To the █████ of the ███

---

The profile image is also a GIF, and since the quality of it in the video is bad, [here's a larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbDfi.gif) of it. I didn't want to include it directly in this post since it's kind of annyoing.

And again, for those who can't run GIFs, the profile image consists of six parts: [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH2Wn.png), [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx5wp.png), [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK27f.png), [fourth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzEmr.png), [fifth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBskk.png), [sixth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu6cn.png).

---

**Hint #1:**

> The substring *"I started from the seemingly perfect state, with clouds<sup>(to which I always returned to for orientation and only changed the height when I had to)</sup> in front of me and earth below"* primarily gives instructions how to rotate the cube when labelling it (keeping the *"seemingly perfect state"*, of course), although one part of it also tells how to hold the cube when starting to *"reconsider the self-image"*.

**IMPORTANT EDIT: (SPOILERS/PARTIAL GIVEAWAY)**

> How do I put this... I apparently used a fake Rubik's cube when making this puzzle (without me knowing it). Sorry for the waste of energy and time if you tried to solve this, I have no excuse for it. The color scheme my cube has is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Q6c.png). I also gave away the orientation [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33187141#33187141). You can downvote this into oblivion if you want, I'd certainly understand it.

**Hint for Orange:**

> This isn't *really* a cipher, even though it does have to do with cryptology. Most of it is just junk, so the plaintext isn't actually 115 characters long.

---

**What are the plaintexts of all the ciphers (including the gray text at the bottom)? Please add reasoning, not only the solution.**

Comment: so much work... :D niice

Comment: Well my first thoughts are that

the users gif is a complete rubik's cube.

This also matches the question they ask:

'I started from the seemingly perfect state' if you look at the users gif of the rubik's cube it is complete. Where it says 'and reconsidered my self-image' suggest we have to rotate it using the 'information I had gathered from others'

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Yeah, and some of the angel names (?) in the related questions have letters UDLRFB capitalized - presumably those are the instructions. I can't do it right now, but if we rotate the cube given by the gif in that way, it should produce a message.

Comment: @Deusovi great spot!

Comment: [I stitched together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuwBn.png) the 3 parts of the webpage (something is missing between part 2 and 3).

Comment: Is it a mistake or important that the tags in the question list are "cipher", in the question body missing entirely, and at the bottom "other questions tagged as cipher, enigmatic puzzle"?

Comment: @IanMacDonald It's a mistake. The tags in the GIF are not a clue.

Comment: @LukasRotter, how do u want us to communicate work in progress? That might bring in collective thinking.

Comment: @WeShall I have nothing against partial answers as long as they solve a part of the puzzle. If there's enough interest, someone could also [start a chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) concerning this puzzle, but I'm not sure if it's necessary in this case. Either way, I can't really decide how you should exchange work in progress, it's up to the moderators & community to decide whether partial answers / comments should be deleted.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! So much work for an amazing riddle. Unfortunately I am stuck at work... Good luck to everyone puzzling :)

I am not sure if that is essential, but the vote number is constantly going down... I also noticed a dot pattern left and right from the question, that might be useful?

Comment: Sometimes I have serious doubts about what is a real story and what is a made-up riddle story :) Good job, @Lukas Rotter

Comment: 500 reputation...

Comment: This weekend, Bounty Hunting :)

Comment: Is it intentional, that some of the "related" words have 2 upper case letters?

Comment: @Sleafar Yes, it is.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please upvote the other answers as well. **[ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45158/15632)** solved half of the ciphers on his own, and **[dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45124/15632)** solved the cube shortly before I did.

---

## Starting position

> As known from the hints the OP is using a [non standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Q6c.png) layout for the Rubik's Cube. We also know that the front of the cube should be white ("with clouds in front of me") and the bottom blue ([as clarified by the OP](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33187141#33187141)). Applying the cube faces from the question gives this:
>
>   [image: start]

### Rotations

> In the [copy of the deleted question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuwBn.png) we can see names of angels on the right side. The capital letters in these names are [instructions that should be applied to the cube](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/).
>
>  `R U LI DI B FI LI FI R DI`
>
>  I have created a tool which performs all these rotations, while preserving the orientation of the letters. This is the final result (click on the image to see all steps):
>
>  [image: final]
>
>  We can see some words on some cube faces: "GOD", "CUBE", "REPEATING", "PRIDE", "SKIP", "MY HOUR". Each face is a hint for the cipher with the corresponding color of the starting position.

### Orange

[Solved by ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45158/15632)

> [*"son of the morning"* (Isaiah 14:12)](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/14-12.htm)

### Yellow

> [image: yellow]
>
>  This is not a hint for the [God's Number](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/gods-number/), but for the [Trifid cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifid_cipher) (which works with a  3×3×3 cube). There are many variants of this cipher, therefore I will simply paste a screenshot created with [this online tool](http://www.geocachingtoolbox.com/index.php?page=trifidCipher):
>
>  [image: trifid cipher]
>
>  [*"I will exalt my throne above the stars of God"* (Isaiah 14:13)](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/14-13.htm)

### White

[Solved by ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45158/15632)

> [*"I will ascend above the heights of the clouds"* (Isaiah 14:14)](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/14-14.htm)

### Blue

> [image: blue]
>
>  This is a variation of the [Ceasar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) (aka. ROT-n). First we need to decrement all letters by 7, giving:
>
>  `FZJIAIZKGDXTOIQY`
>
>  Then we increment the first letter by 0, the second by 1, the third by 2, and so on:
>
>  `FALLENFROMHEAVEN`
>
>  or:
>
>  [*"fallen from heaven"* (Isaiah 14:12)](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/14-12.htm)

### Green

> [image: green]
>
>  The hint for this face is to use the [rail fence cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher) (because of the arrangement of the W's) using an offset of 7, which gives the following:
>
>  `.U.D.W.T.T.E.R.U.D`
>  `C.T.O.N.O.H.G.O.N.`
>
>  or:
>
>  [*"cut down to the ground"* (Isaiah 14:12)](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/14-12.htm)

### Red

[Solved by ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45158/15632)

> [*"brought down to hell"* (Isaiah 14:15)](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/14-15.htm)

### Gray

> All currently found solutions are quotes from [Isaiah 14](http://biblehub.com/kjv/isaiah/14.htm) (probably from the King James Bible - thanks to ffao for correction). Assuming the last quote would be also from this text, this means the solution for the gray part is probably:
>
>  *"Yet thou shalt be brought down to hell, **to the sides of the pit**."* (Isaiah 14:15)

Comment: Nice! Much more efficient than Excel :P

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo I had to guess the initial orientation of symmetric letters. Therefore it's impossible to tell if I'd and O's are placed correctly or upside down. Same applies to M/W.

Comment: @LukasRotter Is the final placement as intended? Is the orientation of the letters relevant at all?

Comment: @Sleafar Yes, your last picture represents the correct placement (not talking about letter orientation here). The orientation just matters in a few instances, i.e. on the green face and on the blue face (I think you can guess it on every other).

Comment: The texts also match other versions (for example, in KJ, the first quote for grey has "sides"/"pit", which would match the 5/3 blank pattern).

Comment: I noticed that the bottom cube has ROT XII - maybe ROT 12?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Already tried all ROTs.

Comment: @Sleafar ah ok. Seems suspicious though...

Comment: I suppose the orange cipher is probably same message  vignere'd twice,  and put aside side by side (AAA..BBB) or like mixed (ABAB..) I don't have enough time to check this (crackpot)  theory.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo The orange cipher has a length of 115, which has the prime factors 5 and 23. If something was repeated there as you suggest, it would have to be 5 times. Initially I thought it could be some variant of Bacon's cipher, but it didn't work with the things I tried.

Comment: isn't it ironic that the seemingly most obvious clue is the only one left? :)

Comment: Just so you (Sleafar, @ffao) know: I will most likely accept Sleafar's answer because it explains every step of the puzzle (assuming Sleafar will add the solved orange and yellow part, of course). I will also award the *current* bounty to Sleafar, but will start another bounty and will quickly award it to ffao. That one will be either +450 or +500, depending on whether ffao solves the yellow part. (for dcfyi I'll maybe award another +200 or so).

Comment: @LukasRotter The other option would be, that I split the current bounty.

Comment: @Sleafar Thanks for the offer, but I honestly want my reputation to go away :P But yeah, maybe I'll just award a +500 bounty to ffao regardless who solves the yellow part. (i.e. equivalent to your splitting suggestion just with more rep)

Comment: God's Number for a 3x3 cube is 20. Perhaps a reference to the Salsa20 cipher? Or perhaps the moves required to solve the "rescrambled" cube with God's Algorithm gives a clue?

Comment: @Draconis Using a modern stream cipher wouldn't produce a ciphertext containing only uppercase letters.

Comment: @Sleafar that must have been a whole lot of work! Congrats to the well deserved bounty :)

Answer (score 19):

After the rotation step, the gimmick is that

> the writings in the faces are hints as to the method used to encrypt the corresponding ciphertexts.

The white face reads

> [image: White face hint]
>
>  *"I will ascend above the heights of the clouds"*
>
>  This was obtained by using a skip cipher with parameter 7 on the text.
>
> ```
>   I......W......I......L......L......A.
>   .....S......C......E......N......D...
>   ...A......B......O......V......E.....
>   .T......H......E......H......E......I
>   ......G......H......T......S......O..
>   ....F......T......H......E......C....
>   ..L......O......U......D......S......
> ```

The red face reads

> [image: Red face hint]
>
>  *"brought down to hell"*
>
>  This is a Gronsfeld cipher with key 315, which is known as the Devil's hour: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witching_hour

The orange face reads

> [image: Orange face hint]
>
>  *"son of the morning"*
>
>   Due to the clue being "repeating", I initially tried to take repeating letters, but that came out a lot of junk. If you take the repeating *bigrams* and *trigrams* instead, you get "so", "no", "ft", "he", "mo", "rn", "ing":
>
>   [image: bigram graph]

Comment: 2 ciphers left, your turn. ;)

Comment: @Sleafar no luck here, I tried a bunch of variations of "twenty" and 20 as keys to ciphers to yellow and got nothing. If we're going by letter count, the plaintext probably is "I will exalt my throne above the stars of God". I think I will need some more divine inspiration for this "devilish" puzzle :)

Comment: That plaintext is my assumption as well. :) But if it's correct it only rules out simple substitution (letter counts don't match) as well as any form of Vigenere ciphers (subtracting letters gives only rubbish). I tried some two letter ciphers, but no luck either.

Comment: That's what I call teamwork (got the last one :). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skaDt.png) are [the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyirG.png) of [the faces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FhAh.png) you solved, in case you would like to include them in your answer.

Answer (score 17):

This is mostly to help others in the process as I'm awful at decrypting ciphers.

So After some poking around I figured out that

> white was the front face

and while chatting with the OP we realized that

> He wasn't using a standard rubik's cube so my colors weren't correctly oriented.
>  So the correct orientation (which the OP told me as well) is:
>  - Yellow as Top,
>  - White as Front,
>  - Orange as Left,
>  - Red as Right,
>  - Blue as Bottom
>  - and Green as Back

Before all of that came to light I realized that the HNQ had some valuable information for me. Which in this case was:

> The moves list to put the cube in the correct placements.

Which gave me this list:

> RULIDIBFILIFIRDI or in the syntax I'm used to
>  RUL'D'BF'L'F'RD'

Which tells me to:

> Turn the the faces in that particular order, where R is right, U is up(top), L is left, D is down, B is back, and F is front.
>  In this notation the letter alone means to rotate clockwise and a letter with I or ' (single quote) is rotate counter-clockwise.

Doing all this gave me this result:

> [image: Rubik's Cube]

Which from that I get these words/sentences/phrases/cryptic-thingies:

> For these _ means an empty spot (a space) and W/M is because I'm not sure if it's an M or a W on the picture.
>
>  GOD33CUBE on the Yellow face
>  PRIDESKIP on the White face
>  REPEATING on the Orange face
>  ROTXII_7_ on the Blue face
>  W/MYHOURGRO on the Red face
>  W/M_W/M_W/M_OF7 on the Green face

And that's where I get stuck...

Comment: God cube is probably 20?

Comment: @bleh Well I know the God number is 20, but that has a 33 on it, so...

Comment: maybe just 660? It's a start

Answer (score 3):

My progress so far, working with a guy who actually knows the Rubik's Cube:
Took a hint from others for

> The angels' names with odd capitalisation
>  But I also noticed the I's and scribed those too.

The clouds and grass

> Are white and green, respectively, giving us the cube's orientation.

Reimagining with information from others

> Is following the aforementioned string as standard move notation, with I's meaning ccw.

Mapping the reference points

> Involves matching up the faces from the avatar gif with the currently scrambled cube.
>  The trick is orientation, which we can get a sense of by what rotation the pieces will undergo when they return to the solved state.
>  Assuming that the colours refer to the centres... We're stuck, trying to find a combination that results in all letters being right way up when unscrambled.

Returned to for orientation, only changing the height when necessary

> Seems to refer to relative orientation, so "towards blue, blue and green towards white"
>  Although maybe "towards white, white and yellow towards blue" makes more sense.
>  Unless you're taking white as front and blue as top, which is what the rest of it suggests...
>  EDIT: I just realised something my teammate had known for a while, regarding orientation of the faces. This probably doesn't relate to this at all.

This is as far as we've figured.
Also yes please to chat room.